# Getting value from non Odoo variable

Tags: python, html, odoo

I'm making a Odoo module with Html, and I'm trying to get the value from a variable in my model. This variable is not a Odoo variable (like fields.Char,fields.Date,fields.Selection...). When I try to show this variable I'm getting an "field not exist" error. I want to know if is possible to retrieve the variable value and pass to a `<h2>` element in my view.

Comment: Im not sure which version of Odoo you are using.  I use v7 and one way you can add a dynamic value to the view is by creating a functional field.  With a functional field you can compute whatever you like on the model, then add it to the xml view.  The functional field is treated like a normal field, but the value that is computed is not stored in the database by default.